# Python Flask error http 404 due to changing static directory

Tags: python, html, css, flask

app.py:

```
class Review(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

@app.route('/reviews/<int:id>')
def full_review(id):
    review = Review.query.get(id)
    return render_template('full_review.html', review=review)
```

full_review.html:
`{% extends 'base.html' %}`
and in base.html file i import css files and pictures:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/style-base.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="static/icon.png"/>
```

but get these errors:

```
"GET /reviews/static/css/style-base.css HTTP/1.1" 404 -
"GET /reviews/static/logo.jpg HTTP/1.1" 404 -
```

i don't know why path changes and how to avoid it

i tryed this

```
{% block styles %}
{{super()}}
{%endblock%}
```

and this:

```
app.static_url_path='/static'
app.static_folder='/static'
```